# use variable (which contains the column-index) in dplyr select

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyeval

When I have a variable like:

```
col_to_select = 2
```

And I want to use the value from that variable in my `dplyr::select`, how would I do that?

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(col_to_select)
```

gives me obviously this error:

```
Error in `select()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `col_to_select` doesn't exist.
```

I know that this has to do with tidy eval. But I just can't find the solution now:/

Comment: It works here (no tidyeval needed), but it is preferable to use `all_of(col_to_select)`.

Comment: It also works here. Maybe you should updated your `dplyr`.

Comment: If we run your code as is, in that order, with current dplyr (e.g. >v1.0) it runs fine without that error. So presumably you are either running your code in a different context (perhaps in a function?) or with an older version of dplyr. Can you please explain more?

Comment: Thanks to all of you!! I think the error must  have been on my side by loading the wrong order...